# Which unsupervised anomaly detection algorithms are there?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I need to create model which will find suspicious entries or anomalies in a network, whose characteristics or features are the `asset_id`, `user_id`, IP accessed from and `time_stamp`.

Which unsupervised anomaly detection algorithms or models should I use to solve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK to use python, thy novelty-detection with sklearn:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html

Comment: I tried this but the results are not that convincing

Answer (score 1):

[Hierarchical Temporal Memory](https://numenta.org) is a model [well suited for anomaly detection](https://numenta.com/assets/pdf/whitepapers/Numenta%20White%20Paper%20-%20Science%20of%20Anomaly%20Detection.pdf). It is also pretty interesting and different from currently typical Deep Learning models.

Comment: I would add the detail that HTM-based algorithms are better suited for cases where you expect a stream of data (i.e. you want to continuously learn and detect anomalies online).